# Move file in client to another drive

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to copy a file from client to network drive using File.Copy("C:\somepath\file.bmp","\xxx\data\file.bmp"). While debugging in local it worked fine, whereas in server it fails to work. I believe File.copy looks in API server's C Drive and it fails to find the file. How do i fix this issue?? Please help me with this...

Comment: Imagine a world where any website you visit could copy any file from your computer.  What you're looking for is an `<input type="file">` for the user to *upload* a file to the server.

Comment: Yes i'm using <input type="File"> to get the path from client... But in API server, File.Copy is what is causing the problem... File.Copy Couldn't find the file...

Comment: Where is `File.Copy` *looking for* the file?  Show the complete code you're using.  If you're trying to access the client's file system, obviously that won't work.

Comment: Yes..i'm trying to access the client file... Is that any other alternative way to achieve this??

Comment: The user has to upload the file.  Again, for obvious reasons, a website can’t access the client’s file system.  Use a file input to allow the user to upload the file.

Comment: Once uploaded, files can be access from the server side using Page.Request.Files or HttpContext.Current.Request.Files

Answer (score 0):

Think of web api as a web application. As such it will have an application pool which means it will execute everything under that particular identity meaning it is bound by the specific rights of that identity.

Second, being a web app, it doesn't have access to anything outside of its own location. This means that you can't access anything on the user's drive and that's a good thing as that would open major security flaws to just about anyone.

Third when you do stuff like this you really want to work with virtual paths. You can have files under your App_Data for example, but you also have to keep in mind what you are copying from where to where.

You will be able to make it work locally depending on where your application is located, but when deployed to a server, the paths will be different hence why you really want to work with virtual paths and you also need to understand the security implications of what you are building.

If you try to upload a file for example,you can do that in a place under the folder where your application is located not outside of it.